# Postgres view with nested SQL query or how to find the last INET

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, sql-view

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orders.email), uuid_nil() AS customer_id, 'Order' AS customer_type, orders.first_name, orders.last_name, MAX(orders.paid_at) AS last_order_at, 1 AS order_count, SUM(orders.total_price_cents) AS total_spent_pennies
FROM orders
WHERE orders.state = 'paid' AND orders.customer_id IS null
GROUP BY orders.email, customer_id, orders.first_name, orders.last_name
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(customers.email), customers.id AS customer_id, 'Customer' AS customer_type, customers.first_name, customers.last_name, MAX(orders.paid_at) AS last_order_at, COUNT(orders.*) AS order_count, SUM(orders.total_price_cents) AS total_spent_pennies
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.email, customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name
```

Which looks like:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| email                         | customer_id                          | customer_type | first_name | last_name    | last_order_at           | order_count | total_spent_pennies |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| blah@gmail.com                | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | Order         | Richard    | Doe          | 2015-12-18 14:45:22 UTC | 1           | 2000                |
| paul@blah.com                 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | Order         | Paul       | Doe          | 2016-04-05 09:04:57 UTC | 1           | 5000                |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

My question is how can I include their last IP address also (INET column).  One dates I can simply use the MAX aggregate function but IP address obviously doesn't have one.

Basically how can I combine this query above to give me a new column with their last_ip address with something like:

```
SELECT browser_ip FROM orders
WHERE email = 'blah@gmail.com'
ORDER BY paid_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get away with a simple subquery like so, you just need to name your queries in order to reference between.

http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/subqueries.php

For example the first part of your query would be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1.email), c1.id AS customer_id, 'Customer' AS customer_type, 
c1.first_name, c1.last_name, MAX(orders.paid_at) AS last_order_at, 
COUNT(orders.*) AS order_count, SUM(orders.total_price_cents) AS total_spent_pennies, 
(SELECT browser_ip FROM orders WHERE c1.email = orders.email 
ORDER BY paid_at DESC LIMIT 1) last_ip
FROM customers c1
JOIN orders ON c1.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY c1.email, c1.id, c1.first_name, c1.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cast to varchar](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createcast.html), and use [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) - something like:

```
SELECT email, paid_at, string_agg(browser_ip::varchar, ',') as ips 
WHERE email = 'blah@gmail.com'
GROUP BY email, paid_at
ORDER BY email, paid_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:

1. Use a LATERAL subquery.  Note this will force a nested loop join.
2. Write a function to retrieve latest IP address and call that.  It will also force a nested loop.
3. Use a window function and a filter on that.  This usually performs even worse since you have to scan the whole table before joining.

In your case, because of the union, I would probably do the second and do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION latest_ip(in_email text)
RETURNS inet LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$
SELECT paid_at, string_agg(browser_ip::varchar, ',') as ips 
WHERE email = in_email
GROUP BY paid_at
ORDER BY paid_at DESC
LIMIT 1
$$;
```

Then you would just call `latest_ip(orders.email)` in your column list

The other would require duplicating the above as a subquery following a LATERAL statement on both branches of your union.  It is worth knowing about, but may be a maintenance problem in this case.